# Function with parameters in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to write a few functions that have parameters in haskell.

For example: I make a list with all kinds of colors, but I want the function to only get the color orange from the list, how do I specify this in the function?

```
getColor :: a -> a
getColor = orange
```

Comment: Can you please add the list to the code block? It may help to see what the problem is.

Comment: I don't have the code to make the list yet

Comment: One of the problems is that you are saying that the getColor should have type `a->a`, but you then declare it with type `a`. You should either change the type to a, or update the function declaration to be `getColor _ = orange` to accept arbitrary color(as per your type declaration `a->a`) and return orange. Does that help a bit?

Comment: I would start by making the code to make the list. How to extract a color will be more clear after that.

Comment: Start by deciding what you want your code to *accomplish*, from start to finish. If you're trying to write a function, you need to decide exactly what you're going to give the function, and what you want it to give back to you. You might want to write an increment function that takes an integer and gives you the next one. Or you might want to write a head function that takes a list with at least one element and gives you the first element of the list. Whatever you want to do, you have to be specific about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want a function that takes a list of many colours and returns a single colour (presumably of your choosing). You should start with a data type to represent your colours.

```
data Colour = Red | Orange | Yellow | Green | Blue
```

now you want a function `getColour` with the type

```
getColour :: Colour -> [Colour] -> Colour
```

which takes a `Colour` and a list of `Colour` and picks out the desired colour from the list. However, lists can be empty, or the list might not contain the colour you want! What will `getColour` return in that case?

In Haskell we handle a function that may not return a result using `Maybe`. The new type of `getColour` is

```
getColour :: Colour -> [Colour] -> Maybe Colour
```

which means `getColour` will either return `Nothing`, or `Just colour` where `colour` is from the list.

Lastly, I'll mention that there are a few ways you could actually write the body of `getColour`, using pattern matching and explicit recursion, or with standard library functions from Haskell's `Prelude`. I assume you're new to Haskell, so I'd recommend the former. Here's some code to get you started:

```
getColour _      []     = Nothing
getColour colour (x:xs) = ...
```

Is this enough to help you write `getColour` by yourself?